# Can I attach php to a class?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

My site creates itineraries based on cities. We carry the selections from one page to the next (using cookies). We want to display php based on the cookies saved from the previous page. For instance, if a customer chooses India as a destination, India's information comes up. If they choose Brazil, Brazil's information will show up.

So far I have:

```
<select name="city">
<option class="level-0" value="india">India</option>
<option class="level-0" value="brazil">Brazil</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">      
var city = getCookie("city");
document.getElementById("city_it").className = city.split(" ")[0];
</script>
```

The div then gives a class of the selected city like this:

```
<div id="city_it" class="india"></div>
```

How can I attach php to the class of a div? Is there a better way to populate information based on customer selections?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, 'attach' php? Do you want to pull in extra content generated from a PHP page?

Comment: By 'attach' php I meant create a condition where if a customer selects a city, a class is formed in a div, and then php can be populated based on the city selected.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. PHP can access cookies via `$_COOKIE`, so you can make decisions on the application side based on the value of the desired cookie.
2. Use AJAX requests to pass call a php file and have it return the content you want.

Such as an example with jquery:

```
$.get('processor.php?city=' + getCookie("city"), function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Ultimately, the notion that php can read the class of a DOM element is not possible because PHP runs on the server and the DOM tree exists in the browser. You have to use Javascript, cookies, or sessions to interact with or predict what changes to make in the DOM tree.

Comment: I've been digging and it seems AJAX is the way to go. How do display it the actual PHP on the next page?

Comment: So, `php` generates `text/html`. `$('.result').html(data);` above places the `data`, which is the `text/html` generated from your `php` script, into DOM elements with class `result`.

Comment: Gotcha, gotcha. Will give it a shot thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the user makes a choice, you would use javascript to send an AJAX message to a PHP script on the server. The AJAX would contain a message telling the server which choice was picked, and the PHP script would return a response with all the needed info to populate the fields. The javascript would then take that response, and use it to modify the UI, populating the fields as needed.

You will want to use something like JSON to transmit data back and fourth between your javascript on your page, and your PHP script on the server.

Comment: Ah, I'm seeing it now. In some examples I've seen they talk about this exact process. Looking up tutorials now, thanks!